# Can logged requests in the chrome devtools network tab be filtered?

Tags: google-chrome, google-analytics, google-chrome-devtools

I'm using the [MVC Mini Profiler](http://code.google.com/p/mvc-mini-profiler/) and Google Analytics in my application.

These are generating calls to the server that lower the signal-to-noise ratio of requests in the log, is it possible to ignore/filter certain requests from the Chrome Dev Tools Network tab so I can focus on the other Ajax requests my app is making?

Comment: Google analytics appears to generate Image requests, so I can filter to XHR, now to filter out MVC Mini Profiler.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The filters at the bottom (All | Documents | Stylesheets | Images | Scripts | XHR | Fonts | WebSockets | Other) let you filter by request type. You can even do multi-select by using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key. If you know what request type you want to ignore, you can select all the other request types.

Note that you may need to click the "Filter" icon (it looks like a funnel) before the filter options will appear.

In case you don't want to filter a particular type of resource, you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to search by URL. You can also use the "Filter" box to filter by URL. <del>(Note that this does an inclusion filter. There is no way to specify an exclusion filter.)</del>

You can use inclusion and exclusion filters in a space seperated list e.g. `logo` as below for only requests containing "logo". **Filtering `-results -negotiate` will filter out MVC mini-profiler results and other requests with "negotiate" in the URL.**

The "Filter" icon, URL filter and request type filters are marked in the image below.

[image: Example of filtering chrome dev tools requests]

Comment: I don't see these filters?

Comment: "There is no way to specify an exclusion filter." There is now. `-results` will filter out requests to the MiniProfiler based on the URL